Cognito + ALB returns 401 only after first login (sign up)
I’ve set up Cognito with an Application Load Balancer (ALB) for authentication. After a user signs up and logs in for the first time, the ALB returns a 401 Unauthorized. However, if the user close the browser tab and opens it again, it works perfectly fine from that point on. Also, if the user logs in again it works like a charm, but after sign up it just returns a 401.
Authentication works fine but only on the first login when the user signups it returns 401 Authorization required.
I have configured properly ALB with the Cognito Integration and in Cognito I have added correctly de callback URL https://alb-domain/oauth2/idpresponse in the Cognito Application. I have followed every AWS tutorial but it does return 401 in the first signup attempt.
I expect this service to work fine with this basic funcionality. If I register correctly, I want to access the ECS application or be redirected to login page for logging in after signup.
I am wondering if this is a bug in Cognito itself because I can not understand why it works perfectly but it does not work on the first login. Or if I have some misconfiguration that I have not double checked.

TL;DR: It seems like a recent bug in AWS Cognito new release. To workaround this, switch to the old hosted UI in Cognito.
I will answer myselft if someone encounters this same issue. It looks like a bug in Cognito new hosted UI, as they have release a new version in 22 Nov. 2024 with a new hosted UI.
If you are using the new Cognito UI with ALB authentication, it will return 401 page when a user is signing up for the first time. This only happens on sign up, then if you log in again in a new tab it will work well. If you switch to the old hosted UI in Cognito, the issue is gone.
I hope they fix it soon as this was released a couple of weeks ago.
